# Set DataFrame row index to a different column

Tags: python, matrix, pandas

### The Setup

Using

```
cell = pd.read_csv('test_cell.txt',header=2,sep='\t')
```

I create a pandas DataFrame object that looks like this:

```
           Name   Description  LN18  22RV1  DU145 
0  100009676_at  LOC100009676  1     2      3     
1      10000_at          AKT3  4     5      6    
2      10001_at          MED6  7     8      9  
3           NaN           NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
```

I'd like to do some matrix multiplication (outer product) with another matrix that has similar rows.  For example:

```
patients =
       id  Pat_1   Pat_2   Pat_3
    0          MED6    1   1   1
    1  LOC100009676    2   2   2
    2          ABCD    3   3   3
```

### Question

These two matrices have some similar row names -- gene symbols.  Since I'm familiar with iterating over dictionaries with keys, how can I establish a "key" column (to column 1 - "Description") with my first pandas DataFrame `cell` such that it matches my other DataFrame `patients` gene symbol keys?

### Ultimately:

I'd like to perform my outerproduct across "MED6","LOC100009676", and so on, and add each gene score down a each patient:cell comparison.  The final data structure is a 1D matrix of 9 entries (given two 3x3 matricies as above).

```
dot_prod_total = sum(np.outer(cell[key], patient[key]).flat for key in cell) 


dot_prod_total =

Pat_1&LN18   Pat_1&22RV1   Pat_1&DU145   Pat_2&LN18   ...
8            10            12            16
```

Thanks to user [@Ivc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/10947/lvc) who helped me out with the dot_prod_total numpy generator comprehension.

Comment: What do you mean by **similar**? Are gene names identical, different, or mostly same with some exceptions?

Comment: By similar, I mean the same.  All gene names will match, `MED6` to `MED6`, etc, by Entrez gene convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is `pd.merge` on the gene names, then sum the scores for each cell:patient pair. But your data frames are reshaped; `pd.stack` is useful for that purpose.

```
cell_s=cell.set_index(['Description','Name']).stack().reset_index()
cell_s.columns = ['Description', 'Name', 'cell', 's1']
```

Then, cell_s looks like this:

```
    Description          Name   cell  s1
0  LOC100009676  100009676_at   LN18   1
1  LOC100009676  100009676_at  22RV1   2
2  LOC100009676  100009676_at  DU145   3
3          AKT3      10000_at   LN18   4
4          AKT3      10000_at  22RV1   5
5          AKT3      10000_at  DU145   6
6          MED6      10001_at   LN18   7
7          MED6      10001_at  22RV1   8
8          MED6      10001_at  DU145   9
....
```

Do it again for patients:

```
patients_s=patients.set_index('id').stack().reset_index()
patients_s.columns=['id', 'patient', 's2']
```

Then, join the two and product two scores:

```
merged=cell_s.merge(patients_s, left_on='Description',right_on='id')
merged['score']=merged.s1*merged.s2
```

It looks like :

```
     Description          Name   cell  s1            id patient  s2  score
0   LOC100009676  100009676_at   LN18   1  LOC100009676   Pat_1   2      2
1   LOC100009676  100009676_at   LN18   1  LOC100009676   Pat_2   2      2
2   LOC100009676  100009676_at   LN18   1  LOC100009676   Pat_3   2      2
3   LOC100009676  100009676_at  22RV1   2  LOC100009676   Pat_1   2      4
4   LOC100009676  100009676_at  22RV1   2  LOC100009676   Pat_2   2      4
5   LOC100009676  100009676_at  22RV1   2  LOC100009676   Pat_3   2      4
6   LOC100009676  100009676_at  DU145   3  LOC100009676   Pat_1   2      6
...
```

Finally, groupby and sum the scores:

```
scores=merged.groupby(['patient','cell'])['score'].sum()
```

You get `scores` like this:

```
patient  cell 
Pat_1    22RV1    12
         DU145    15
         LN18      9
Pat_2    22RV1    12
         DU145    15
         LN18      9
Pat_3    22RV1    12
         DU145    15
         LN18      9
```

### For comment

For plotting scores as a histogram, pandas has `hist()` methods.

```
scores = scores.reset_index()
#Plot a histogram with all scores:
scores.hist()
#Plot a histogram with specific cells:
cells = your_map['tissue_1']  #e.g. cells = ['LN18', 'DU145']    
scores[scores.cell.isin(cells)].hist()
#or get the score array and input this to your plotting functions
score_array = scores[scores.cell.isin(cells)].score.values
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but this confuses my next steps.  When I compute my answer across all cell types, I get a list that I plot as a histogram.   From there, I plot a second overlaid histogram that only includes cell types from a certain organ.  So using your approach, how can I: 1) plot the scores as a histogram in a memory-conscious way, and 2) extract the scores belonging to the certain cell types to plot those as well?  Mind you I have a dictionary that maps {tissue_1: [cell_1a, cell_1b, ... cell_1n], tissue_2: [cell_2a, cell_2b, ... cell_2n], ...} and so on.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is it solve your remaining problems?

Comment: Your solution makes sense, as does your method of plotting the cell-specific histogram.  If I wanted to plot the Kolmolgorov-Smirnov score, could I use `scores` as one distribution, and `scores[scores.cell.isin(cells)]` as the other?  They are both numpy arrays, yes?

Comment: No, `scores` are `pd.Series` object. If you want to get numpy array from this, use `.values`; e.g. `scores.values` and `scores[scores.cell.isin(cells)].score.values` are the numpy arrays.

Comment: Apologies, but when I run >>> `scores.hist()`, I get `TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()` The porton of axes.py that gives this error should only do so when `bin` is specified as a hist parameter.  However, even specifying `bin` does not solve the problem.  I continue to get the error and a figure with 4 empty subplots.  Is this a matter of version?  I'm on pandas version 0.12.0

Comment: I checked above code works and my pandas version is 0.16.1. I need more details to figure out what is the problem. By the way, I'm not sure it is just a typo but there is no `bin` option for `hist`; what it has a `bins` option.